# Is Ultrasonic Self Balancing Robot Possible?

Tags: arduino, balance

a quick question, can i make a SBR using UNO and two HC-SR04 knowing that this configuration offers a 1.36 mm resolution  (i.e it increment 1.36mm) ?

Comment: could you explain how you place your srf?

Comment: the surface is horizontal, no inclinations

Comment: im not sure there is a possible way to create sbr only using srf, because srf is distance sensor, not giving you any information about orientation of robot. You need gyroscope or anything similliar

Comment: wait a minute.. i figure out a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not - it can take about 60ms to get a reading from those sensors[†](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Proximity/HCSR04.pdf), which is quite slow for the loop updating a balancing robot.

Comment: i believe yes, even interrupt based program (with sensors 2cm above ground) will read 14 "1.36cm" steps (20 / 1.36) each taking 4ms, the loop time is (you are right 60ms), just re edit you answer

Comment: and as an evidence a quadcopter loop time is 4ms and i hardly balance (at least DIYs) so expect what a 60ms might do